# How to convert a vim tab into a vertical split?

Tags: linux, vim

I have used VS Code and liked the way we can drag-drop the window to the right to create a vertical split.

Sometimes I open many files with vim *(`vim -p *py`)*. When going through the tabs, I feel like this specific tab should be a vertical split instead.

Forgetting the drag and drop part, how can I make my current tab to be splitted vertically? (I've had `splitright` set)

#### EDIT:

As suggested by [sparrow1029](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/538375/22240), `:vs sb#` works, but keeps the former buffer intact, can we delete it somehow? Maybe some function bound to keystroke(s)?

Comment: Okay, so I found [these](https://vim.fandom.com/wiki/Move_current_window_between_tabs) functions on the vim wiki. Replace the calls to `sp` in the functions with `vs`, and map them to a keystroke, and it should have the desired effect. If it works for you, I will update my answer :)

Comment: FYI: the hierarchy in Vim is tabs contain windows (which you're calling a vertical split), and windows show buffers, which exist independently of tabs and windows (different windows may show the same buffer, for instance). With that in mind, you might want to rephrase your question in a way that makes more sense in Vim.

Comment: *":vs sb# works, but keeps the former buffer intact, can we delete it somehow?"* Is [`:argdelete`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#%3Aargdelete) what you're looking for? That will remove it from arguments, so that `:n` and `:prev` will not go through that particular buffer anymore...

Comment: I want the buffer to be killed.

Answer (score 10):

If you read [this article](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/), it will help you understand the differences between `buffers`, `windows`, and `tabs` in vim.

[This answer](https://superuser.com/questions/134176/how-to-split-existing-buffer-vertically-in-vim/134178#answer-134178) on superuser has one solution:

> The `vs` and `vsplit` commands take a filename as an argument like `:vs somefile` to open a file in a vertical split.
>
> To put an existing buffer in a split window you use the `sb#` command (where # is the buffer number). Splits in VIM default to horizontal, to change this, prefix your command with vert which forces a vertical split of the next split command.
>
> `:vert sb#`

where `#` is the number of the buffer you want to show as a split in the current window.

To show your currently active buffers you can use `:ls!` or `:buffers`.

[Solution #1](https://joshldavis.com/2014/04/05/vim-tab-madness-buffers-vs-tabs/#solution-1-replicating-tabs-with-buffers) on the previously linked article about vim windows/tabs/buffers suggests [airline](https://github.com/vim-airline/vim-airline) plugin for vim to show currently open buffers as you might expect 'tabs' to work in other editors.

Comment: Umm... I was already aware of the differences. The answers on the previous question were helpful. But I was looking for kinda a function hooked to a keybinding to do the split for current buffer automatically.

Comment: Gotcha! Sorry, I only found out recently about all the differences, was trying to be helpful. Would you want it to split with the next or previous buffer? Or be able to specify?

Comment: I'll update my question with details.

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: Use buffers instead of tabs in Vim.

If I understand correctly, the problem is that you want to keep that file in a split window *while* you change the file on the other side, so that you can keep the other file visible.

It turns out that tabs in Vim don't really work that way, tabs are collections of windows, so whenever you change tabs, you'll switch all windows at once. That's quite useful if you're working on separate sets of windows at the same time.

But it looks like that's not what you want, since you want to change the file in a single window at a time.

For that purpose, you'll want to use **buffers** in Vim, and not tabs. Buffers are the Vim features that most closely ressembles tabs in other editors such as VS Code.

Simply use `vim *.py` when opening files (without the `-p` option that opens them in tabs), and navigate them using `:n` and `:prev` (or `:N`). You can then split with `:vs` or `:sp` and use the Ctrl-W commands to switch and reorganize windows.

Employ tabs if you ever find yourself wanting to have a separate set of windows, or perhaps focus on a single file full-screen for a while, while at the same time preserving the previous window setup you had, coming back to it at any time.

You might want to read [`:help buffers`](https://vimhelp.org/windows.txt.html) (linked here), it goes into quite a bit of detail into all these concepts.

Answer (score 1):

I feel that the answers are good theoretically but none actually address the workflow.

To work with split screens,

```
vim file1 (or just vim)
```

once inside

```
ctrl+w v --> vertical split
ctrl+w h --> horizontal split
```

Open a new file

```
:n file3
```

or in parent directory.

```
:n ../file4
```

or to open multiple files

```
:n file1 file2 file3 ../file4
```

to switch between them

```
:n
```

As the previous answer already state we utilize vim `buffers` here.